# How to do if dont want to read the whole string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, int

What should I do if I have a combination of numbers and symbol, then I want to read only the numbers without the symbol. Example,I had this type of number :

```
626120524133452_1400231752
```

By using C#, is there has any possible way to NOT read the whole string, i just want to read the number before the underlined..

```
626120524133452 >> like this
```

What I suppose to do? Please give some idea guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string is just a sequence of chars that can be queried:

```
var input = "626120524133452_1400231752";

var firstNumber = new string(input.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "626120524133452_1400231752";
int index = s.IndexOf('_');
string result = s.Substring(0, index);
Console.WriteLine(result); // Print 626120524133452
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string if this is sure that _ symbol will be used a separator.
This is a demo of how to do (there are several options in split as well, try using them)

```
string str="626120524133452_1400231752";
string[] newstr=str.Split('_');
string final=newstr[0];
```

Comment: string.Split does not take string, pass character, str.Split('_');